# how to pass data from one component to another without refreshing data(using service)

Tags: angular

```
@Injectable({
      providedIn: 'root',
    })
    export class PassDataService {
      public data = {};
    
     setData(passdata: any): void {
        this.data = passdata;
      }
    }
```

My list  **list.ts**

```
    this.passdata.setData('2');
```

Detail.ts

```
this.passdata.setData.subscribe((channel) => (this.id = channel));
```

Please let me know what is wrong in this code.Thanks in Advance!

Comment: Hi @payal, you can pass data using `Subject` in your service, checkout this [link](https://jasonwatmore.com/post/2019/02/07/angular-7-communicating-between-components-with-observable-subject). let me know if you need more help in this. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Well, you just have to use rxjs-subjects and observables to solve this.
Example:

1. In your service.ts, create a subject (essentially is the source for storing the data you have to pass) and create an observable from this subject.

Import using - `import { BehaviorSubject, EMPTY, ReplaySubject } from 'rxjs';`

```
  private _selectedCustomerSource = new BehaviorSubject<any>({ status: false, data: null });
  selectedCustomerData$ = this._selectedCustomerSource.asObservable();

  setSelectedCustomer(isSelected, selectedCustomer) {
    this._selectedCustomerSource.next({ status: isSelected, data: selectedCustomer })
  }
```

2. in your parent component, you can set the value of source you have created.

```
this._service.setSelectedCustomer(//data here);
```

3. in your child component, subscribe the observable to access the data stored in the source

```
this._transaction.selectedCustomerData$.subscribe(res => this.selectedCustomerData = res)
```

Note: You have to unsubscribe the observable ondestroy to reset the source.